# Use of struct initialization syntax for on-heap struct

Tags: c, struct, initialization, heap-memory

I have this simple structure I want to initialize on the heap and return as a pointer in a function.

```
struct entry {
    const char* const key; // We don't want the key modified in any way
    const void* data;      // But the pointer to data can change
    struct entry* next;
};
```

There is one problem, I cannot `calloc` it and initialize members one by one because `key` is a const pointer. I found somewhere this syntax that works:

```
struct entry* entry = calloc(1, sizeof(struct entry));
*entry = (struct entry) { .key = key, .data = data, .next = NULL };
```

But I don't know what is going on with it: does it create an "anonymous" struct that is then copied to the place where `*entry` lives? Is that safe to use or should I prefer creating a local struct that is then copied with `memcpy` to the right location?

Comment: Are you sure that works, because it shouldn't. What is the type of `entry`?

Comment: `entry` is a `struct entry*`. I add the declaration part in the question.

Comment: As I suspected, it won't compile: https://ideone.com/2YIgUN

Comment: I just noticed that you also suggested memcpy, so yeah that is the correct approach. :-s

Comment: Strange... With your file: `clang -std=c11 -Weverything -pedantic struct_test.c  -o struct_test` yields no error for me.

Comment: gcc correctly complains and clang doesn't. Looks like a compiler bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The assignment you presented is not correct and should not compile.

The correct way of initializing an allocated struct with const members is to allocate some memory, create a temporary struct entry object, and then use memcpy to copy the object to the allocated memory:

```
void* mem = malloc( sizeof( struct entry ) );
struct entry temp = { key , data , NULL };
memcpy( mem , &temp , sizeof( temp ) );
struct entry* e = mem;
```

Comment: Is it really safe to `memcpy` new values over `const` fields?

Comment: Wait, never mind, you are not doing that, `mem` does not have a type yet. But leaving the comment in case someone else wonders about it.

Comment: @hyde Yes, memcpy sets the effective type to the object.

Comment: Is it a problem to use `e` instead of `mem` the whole way in your sample? (I guess you used `mem` to avoid this issue entirely)

Comment: @M.M It makes no difference what points to an object. The object before memcpy doesn't have an effective type. Since this is way beyond OP's understanding I used void to imply it.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
*entry = (struct entry) { .key = key, .data = data, .next = NULL };
```

uses the assignment operator. The conditions for assignment operator (C11 6.5.16/2) include:

> **Constraints**
>
> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

The definition of *modifiable lvalue* can be found in 6.3.2.1/1:

> A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-qualified type.

So `*entry` is not a modifiable lvalue, because its type is a struct that has a member with const-qualified type. Therefore it is a **constraint violation** to have `*entry` appear on the left-hand-side of the assignment operator.

The clang compiler (all versions I tried) appears to not give any diagnostic message for this constraint violation; this is clearly a compiler bug. gcc does give a diagnostic.

---

Regarding the second part of the question:

> should I prefer creating a local struct that is then copied with memcpy to the right location?

As also explained by 2501, you can do this in C when writing into space allocated by the `malloc` family.   (If you had declared a named `struct entry` object then it is less clear whether `memcpy`ing over it is permitted).

Comment: memcpy-ing over an object of type struct entry (or any other type) that doesn't have allocated storage duration would cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @2501 can you provide standard references for that

Comment: 9899:2011 Expressions 6.5 paragraphs 6 and 7

Comment: I made a mistake, above comments are not relevant. The problem is with const, not aliasing. Sorry. :-/ memcpy-ing over a type struct entry is ub becase of 6.7.3 p6, since one of the members is const.

Comment: @2501 the 6.7.3p6 talks about writing using a non-const lvalue. `memcpy` doesn't write with an lvalue. I've seen people say memcpy should be treated the same as a series of assignment of `unsigned char` but I don't think the actual text in the standard is solid.  Unclear wording imo, although I agree that the most sensible thing that the standard *should* say is that you can't memcpy over the object declared const.

Comment: Read 7.24.1. p1 and p3. The lvalue is unsigned char.